# Qiskit predecessor and successor map of DAG circuits

Tags: programming, qiskit

I am trying to figure out how to use the functions ["_make_pred_succ_maps"](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/master/qiskit/dagcircuit/_dagcircuit.py). Here is a description of the function from Github:

```
def _make_pred_succ_maps(self, n):
    """Return predecessor and successor dictionaries.
    Args:
        n (int): reference to self.multi_graph node id
    Returns:
        tuple(dict): tuple(predecessor_map, successor_map)
            These map from wire (Register, int) to predecessor (successor)
            nodes of n.
    """
```

Nevertheless, I do not understand how to interpret outputs like the following:

```
>>> circuit_name._make_pred_succ_maps(1)
({}, {(QuantumRegister(3, 'a'), 0): 10})

>>> circuit_name._make_pred_succ_maps(2)
({(QuantumRegister(3, 'a'), 0): 41}, {})
```

What do the individual numbers mean?

Comment: I'm not familar with this function, but `QuantumRegister(3, 'a')` describes a register of three qubits, with the register assigned the name `'a'`.

Comment: @JamesWootton Thank you for this info. Do you know what the other numbers mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(QuantumRegister(3, 'a'), 0)`
 means the 0th qubit in a QuantumRegister called `'a'` of size 3.

The other numbers (10 and 41) are node ids for the predecessors and successors of the node.

So what `({(QuantumRegister(3, 'a'), 0): 41}, {})` is saying is there is an edge from node 41 along wire `(QuantumRegister(3, 'a'), 0)` that ends at node 2 (the node you provided) and that this node has no successors as the second dict is empty.

It is also worth noting this is a private function and so should not really be used in this way.